# Kentico media library custom file upload

Tags: c#, content-management-system, kentico

I'm working with kentico v6.0.58 (SP1)‎ and there is default media library functionality, I'm trying to add an ability to upload .ics files (no processing required), I've updated content>media and system>files tabs in CMSSiteManager to allow that particular extension, but I'm still getting an error stating that I can not upload files with ics extension, any ideas are appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a separate setting for media libraries. You should be able to find it under `Content->Media->Security->Media file allowed extensions`.

Comment: Did you set it globally or for a specific site? If globally, does the site inherit the settings?

Comment: I've set it for specific site - that's for sure, don't know how to check inheritance though, I'm not very good with kentico...

Comment: ok looks like it was set globally instead of being set for that particular site, thanks, it helped